# Can the iOS Scriptable app change the location of Home Screen apps; if not why not?

Tags: ios, applications, automation, mobile-device-management, javascript-automation

From what I can see, the iOS Scriptable app has far more access to the functions of iOS apps than say Shortcuts, plus it’s probably easier to script since it’s actually code you type instead of Shortcuts’ drag and drop menu.

However, I have not seen any command in the API / documentation for changing the location of an app on the Home Screen. One time, Bing Chat suggested I get some ID of an app, like com.something.Internet, then update some location property of an App(“ID”) instantiated on its ID, to something like Position(1, 0).

I am pretty sure it was wrong since I do not see this “App” command / object in the Scriptable built-in command reference.

Can I please get absolute confirmation that this is not possible, and more specifically, why? Although Apple grants access to the underlying APIs of the various apps, if they for some reason do not want to give anyone access to being able to modify the Home Screen programmatically, like auto-moving or removing apps, why? Is it a security thing, or a choice about the “Apple experience”, for the user?

Comment: Would't it be easiest to ask the developer what their app can do?  He is active on Twitter and Mastodon.  Asking why Apple does or does not allow something would be off-topic.